# Select objects based on value of other nested attributes using regex with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "digest": "sha256:ab5e999ae06daefd488f3b44a54e75cc1f2e13920cbdece9b28271e4b9d69500"
    }
  ],
  "name": "latest"
}
{
  "images": [
    {
      "digest": "sha256:44815925453c50637a53d4d8fb7903d0880fa76bdc37a76b127f68410bc39a35"
    }
  ],
  "name": "tmp_118a872e760bfe4275b489b17ddf2cfbf692ff55"
}
{
  "images": [
    {
      "digest": "sha256:ab5e999ae06daefd488f3b44a54e75cc1f2e13920cbdece9b28271e4b9d69500"
    }
  ],
  "name": "0.1.0"
}
```

I am using jq and want to get the "digest" elements of the objects where "name" follows the regular expression "^tmp_[0-9a-zA-z]*"

What i know:

```
# how to get all the names
cat json_file | jq '.name'

Outputs:
"latest"
"tmp_118a872e760bfe4275b489b17ddf2cfbf692ff55"
"0.1.0"


# how to get all the digest values
cat json_file | jq -r '.images|.[]|.digest'

Outputs:
sha256:ab5e999ae06daefd488f3b44a54e75cc1f2e13920cbdece9b28271e4b9d69500
sha256:44815925453c50637a53d4d8fb7903d0880fa76bdc37a76b127f68410bc39a35
sha256:ab5e999ae06daefd488f3b44a54e75cc1f2e13920cbdece9b28271e4b9d69500
```

Comment: Please clarify what the regex selection criterion should be. Did you perhaps mean '^tmp' or maybe "tmp_"? (Testing for the regex "tmp*" would be equivalent to testing for "tm", so it seems unlikely that "tmp*" is the regex you really wanted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [select](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/uv0bjiokwk-use-jq-to-filter-objects-list-with-regex) function you can extract an attribute using a regex.

```
# the solution
cat json_file | jq -r 'select(.name|test("^tmp_[0-9a-zA-z]*")) | .images|.[]|.digest'

# output:
sha256:44815925453c50637a53d4d8fb7903d0880fa76bdc37a76b127f68410bc39a35
```

Comment: `tmp*` would be an incorrect RE: e.g.: it matches `tm` also. You probably meant `tmp.*`, but then it's redundant, simply `tmp` would suffice (OP does not specify any requirement where `tmp` should be matched).